# Having trouble applying event listeners to <divs>

Tags: javascript, loops, event-handling

Hey guys I'm creating an email app and I have an issue when I'm printing out the emails to the inbox screen for each user.  Each email in the inbox is a preview of the email in a .  I want to attach an onclick event listener to each  in order to have it clickable where if you click it you get a page of the actual full body of the email.

My function open_email() takes an argument that is the email ID. this is what I will use to bring up the email. But I need to pass the proper ID in.

The way it's working now is the ID is always '1' which is the ID first email I created.

I can't figure out why it's changing each  ID to '1'.  There has to be something wrong with my code in the loops that I am missing.

Can anyone find it?  Thanks!

```
  if (mailbox == "inbox") {
    fetch('/emails/inbox')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {
      const element = document.getElementById("emails-view");
      for (index = 0; index < emails.length; index++) {
        var x = emails[index].id
        if (emails[index].read == false) {
          element.innerHTML += '<div class="emails unread">' + "From:" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].sender) +
          "<p class='subject'>" + "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(emails[index].subject) + "</p>" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].timestamp) + '</div>';
          element.onclick = () => open_email(x)
        }else{
          element.innerHTML += '<div class="emails">' + "From:" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].sender) +
          "<p>" + "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(emails[index].subject) + "</p>" + JSON.stringify(emails[index].timestamp) + '</div>';
          element.onclick = () => open_email(x)
        }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an event listener to the *whole container* and overwriting it every iteration of the loop. Instead, add a listener to the appended element.

A problem is that using `innerHTML +=` will corrupt existing listeners inside the container, so use `appendChild` instead:

```
const container = document.getElementById("emails-view");
for (const email of emails) {
    const { read, id, timestamp, sender, subject } = email;
    const emailDiv = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    emailDiv.className = read ? 'emails' : 'emails unread';
    emailDiv.innerHTML = `
        From: ${JSON.stringify(sender)}
        <p class='subject'>Subject: ${JSON.stringify(subject)}</p> ${timestamp}
    `;
    emailDiv.onclick = () => open_email(id);
}
```

That's the general idea - but there's another problem. Concatenating HTML strings from user input can result in arbitrary code execution. To prevent unsafe code from being run, make sure that the values being put into the HTML don't contain HTML tag delimiters (`<` and `>`).

```
const clean = str => str
  .replaceAll('<', '&lt;')
  .replaceAll('>', '&gt;');
```

and use, eg:

```
From: ${JSON.stringify(clean(sender))}
```

Or, even better, sanitize the text before putting it into the database.

(do you really need `JSON.stringify` everywhere? that seems strange, remove it if you can)

Comment: thank you so much for helping - it's the append.child that I think is the problem - you are right. I'm going to focus on that.  However, I used your code and it's not working for me.  I already have the emails created so I don't need the array you created.  It's very confusing can we go to chat and you help me a little please? thanks

Comment: We can talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223728/room-for-certainperformance-and-card51short